# Expectation value of a sum of operators, $A+B$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

Expectation value of an operator $A$ is defined as: $\langle A\rangle=\langle\psi|A| \psi\rangle=\sum_{n} a_{n} \mathcal{P}_{a_{n}}$
where $a_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\mathcal{P}_{a_{n}}$ is it's probability of occurance.

If $C=A+B$ having eigenstates and eigenvalues $(\left|c_{i}\right\rangle$, $c_n)$, such that none of $\left|c_{i}\right\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $A$ or $B$, its expectation value will be
$\langle C\rangle=\langle\psi|A+B| \psi\rangle=\langle A\rangle+\langle B\rangle= \sum_{n} a_{n} \mathcal{P}_{a_{n}}   + \sum_{n} b_{n} \mathcal{P}_{b_{n}}=\sum_{n} c_{n} \mathcal{P}_{c_{n}}$

Is there another way to see how

> $\sum_{n} a_{n} \mathcal{P}_{a_{n}}   + \sum_{n} b_{n} \mathcal{P}_{b_{n}}=\sum_{n} c_{n} \mathcal{P}_{c_{n}}$

I'm interested in it because it appears to me that the eigenstates, eigenvalues and probabilities of $C$ i.e
$\left|c_{i}\right\rangle$, $\mathcal{P}_{c_{n}}$,
$c_n$ can have any value irrespective of    $(\left|a_{i}\right\rangle$, $\mathcal{P}_{a_{n}}$,
$a_n)$ and    $(\left|b_{i}\right\rangle$, $\mathcal{P}_{b_{n}}$,
$b_n)$ so it's surprising how they are connected as $\sum_{n} a_{n} \mathcal{P}_{a_{n}}   + \sum_{n} b_{n} \mathcal{P}_{b_{n}}=\sum_{n} c_{n} \mathcal{P}_{c_{n}}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you want as an answer to this question - you already know how to show that this statement is true (and in fact, this is how expectation values of *all* random variables behave, not just in QM), and you haven't explained to us at all why it "appears" to you that the eigenstates and values of $C$ can "have any value irrespective" of those of $A$ and $B$. I don't understand this at all - $C$ is the *sum* of $A$ and $B$, why do you refuse to believe that its properties should be related to those of its summands?!

Comment: A state can be an eigenstate of $C$ without being an eigenstate of either of $A$ or $B$.

As a simple example, consider 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is an eigenvector of $C$ but not of $A$ and not of $B$.

Comment: Found the above example here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475896/eigenvalue-of-a-sum-of-operator

Comment: I don't see how that's a response to my comment. I didn't claim that the eigenvectors of $C$ had to be the *same* as those of $A$ or $B$, I just said that I don't understand your claim that they can have "any value irrespective[...]". The equation you're asking about in your question *also* doesn't imply that the eigenvectors of $C$ should be the same as those of $A$ or $B$ - perhaps you think it does? If you do, you should explain why you think so.

Comment: I think I was confused. Your comments made me think again . I'm sorry for taking your time, I'm self studying QM and it's a bit hard for me. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I agree with @ACuriousMind: you have the relation $A+B=C\Rightarrow\langle A\rangle+\langle B\rangle=\langle C\rangle$. Then you've found some way to write $\langle D\rangle$ for any operator $D$... and that's it!

Comment: @Quantum Mechanic , yes I agree now. I was just confused. It's first introduction to qm and I'm self studying so I just slipped.

Comment: @Kashmiri no problem - keep asking questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is somewhat misleading here, since probabilities $\mathcal{P}_{a_n}$, $\mathcal{P}_{b_n}$ and $\mathcal{P}_{c_n}$ actually refer to different eigenbases. Thus, if operator $A$ has eigenstates $|a_n\rangle$, i.e., $A|a_n\rangle=a_n|a_n\rangle$, then
$$\mathcal{P}_{a_n}^A=|\langle a_n|\psi\rangle|^2,$$
and similarly
$$\mathcal{P}_{b_n}^B=|\langle b_n|\psi\rangle|^2,
\mathcal{P}_{c_n}^C=|\langle c_n|\psi\rangle|^2,$$
so that the relation takes form
$$
\sum_na_n\mathcal{P}_{a_n}^A+
\sum_nb_n\mathcal{P}_{b_n}^B=
\sum_nc_n\mathcal{P}_{c_n}^C.
$$
Note that the summation over $n$ is misleading as well, as the different space are not necessarily indexed in the same way and not necessarily mapped one-to-one among each other.